# Aggregation on property / calculated field

Tags: django

Let's say I have following (simplified) model, where a Car is weighted. Sometimes there are persons in the car (but not always) and hence I have a `@property` to calculate the `net_weight` of the Car.

```
class CarWeight(models.Model):
    total_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    person_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def net_weight(self):
        if self.person_weight:
            return self.total_weight - self.person_weight
        else:
            return self.total_weight

    def __unicode__(self):
        if self.person_weight > 0:
            return u"%s (excl. persons)" % (self.total_weight - self.person_weight)
        else:
            return u"%s" % self.total_weight
```

Now I'd like to get the minimum, maximum and average net weights of my collection of `CarWeight` objects.

I thought I could do `CarWeight.objects.aggregate(Avg('net_weight'), Max('net_weight'), Min('net_weight'))`, but that yields `Cannot resolve keyword 'net_weight' into field`.
Apparently properties aren't supported as a parameter there (only real fields are).

I searched SO and found that I might need to use `.extra()` but have trouble getting this to work.

Note: I do not want to denormalize (by storing net_weight and overriding `save()`).

Using Django 1.8 and Postgres.

**Edit**

As suggested, when I try with aggregate first and then doing annotate, I get wrong results:

```
>>> CarWeight.objects.all()
[<CarWeight: 100.0>, <CarWeight: 120.0>]
>>> CarWeight.objects.annotate(net_val=Sum('total_weight')-Sum('person_weight'))
[<CarWeight: 100.0>, <CarWeight: 120.0>]
>>> CarWeight.objects.annotate(net_val=Sum('total_weight')-Sum('person_weight')).aggregate(Avg('net_val'), Max('net_val'), Min('net_val'))
{'net_val__avg': None, 'net_val__max': None, 'net_val__min': None}
>>> CarWeight.objects.create(total_weight=500, person_weight=100)
<CarWeight: 400 (excl. persons)>
>>> CarWeight.objects.annotate(net_val=Sum('total_weight')-Sum('person_weight')).aggregate(Avg('net_val'), Max('net_val'), Min('net_val'))
{'net_val__avg': 400.0, 'net_val__max': Decimal('400.0'), 'net_val__min': Decimal('400.0')}
>>> CarWeight.objects.annotate(net_val=Sum('total_weight')-Sum('person_weight'))
[<CarWeight: 400.0 (excl. persons)>, <CarWeight: 100.0>, <CarWeight: 120.0>]
```

**Edit2**:

The workaround for this is setting person_weight to "0" by default instead of empty. Then the calculation can take place without problems.

```
person_weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=1, default=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
result = CarWeight.objects.annotate(net_val=Sum('total_weight')-Sum('person_weight')).aggregate(Avg('net_val'),Max('net_val'),Min('net_val'))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Anush, I've updated my question. Unfortunately this doesn't work as only the objects that have a `person_weight` set are taken into account.

Comment: However, the workaround for this is setting `person_weight` to "0" by default instead of empty. Since `blank=True, null=True` wasn't specified originally, let me accept this answer. I'll update my question accordingly.